# PHP base64_encode giving different result to Javascript btoa

Tags: javascript, php, base64

I have the dummy account:
Username: giancagallardo@gmail.com
Password: Av3$truz

When I try to use PHP base64_encode using the code `base64_encode($userName . ":" . $password);`

I get "*Z2lhbmNhZ2FsbGFyZG9AZ21haWwuY29tOkF2Mw*"

When I use Javascript BTOA using the code `btoa(userName + ":" + password)`
I get "*Z2lhbmNhZ2FsbGFyZG9AZ21haWwuY29tOkF2MyR0cnV6*".

I am supposed to be getting the second one in PHP, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on the values you have provided, Z2lhbmNhZ2FsbGFyZG9AZ21haWwuY29tOkF2Mw only contains Av3. This means that whatever you are passing to base64_encode, is not encoded correctly.

Comment: how can I make it read the rest? it should also be reading "$truz"

3v4l.org/TDK6E

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is your code:

```
$userName = "giancagallardo@gmail.com";
$password = "Av3$truz";

echo base64_encode($userName . ":" . $password);
```

PHP is trying to get the value of `$truz`, change it to this:

```
$userName = "giancagallardo@gmail.com";
$password = 'Av3$truz'; //now it does not try to evaluate it or you could scape $ like "Av3\$truz"

echo base64_encode($userName . ":" . $password);
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same results.

```
echo base64_encode('hello' . ':' . 'how are you?');
```

[PHP eval](https://3v4l.org/srbrm)

```
alert(btoa('hello' + ':' + 'how are you?'));
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qp0tgz28/)

The result is in both cases:

```
aGVsbG86aG93IGFyZSB5b3U/
```

In case you don't get the same, can you give an example, just like I did?

Note that character encoding might be a factor here, but it is probably more likely that your variables don't have the same content.

Comment: I am using:

$username= "giancagallardo@gmail.com";
$password = "Av3$truz";

And for Javascript:

var userName = "giancagallardo@gmail.com";
var password = "Av3$truz"; 

and I get those results

Comment: https://3v4l.org/TDK6E

I should be getting "Z2lhbmNhZ2FsbGFyZG9AZ21haWwuY29tOkF2MyR0cnV6"